# How do grubby and grimy differ?

Tags: difference, word-difference

How do grubby and grimy differ?

Definition of *grubby* by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grubby):

> dirty; slovenly:
>   children with grubby faces and sad eyes.

Definition of *grimy* by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grimy?s=ts):

> covered with grime; dirty:
>   I shook his grimy hand.

Definition of *grime* by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grime):

> to cover with dirt; make very dirty; soil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would use [grubby](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grubby) to describe informally and/or disapprovingly something is not very pleasant. You can use it about something is not very clean, and also about somebody's behaviour.

**grimy** is neither informal nor disapproving. It specifically describes something that is covered in grime, which the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grime) defines as **a layer of dirt on skin or on a building**.

Grubby has more emotional significance: it's something that you wouldn't want to come into contact with, like a small child whose face is covered with food and snot, or a t-shirt that has been worn for a few days without washing.

Grimy simply states that someone or something is covered in dirt, for example a miner who has just finished a shift and is covered in coal dust, or the building that is next to the mine entrance.